# New Pythagorean triples from old: a geometric proof?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, pythagorean-triples

There is a well-known construction that shows that in a right triangle with sides $a\le b<c$, we have $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Inscribe a square of side $c$ into a square of side $a+b$ so that each vertex of the inner square partitions a side of the outer square into segments of lengths $a$ and $b$ in that order, say, clockwise.

I am curious if there is a similarly nice geometric proof that shows the following: if $a\le b<c$ are sides of a right triangle, then so are $2a+b+2c\le a+2b+2c<2a+2b+3c$.

For example, applying this transformation to $(3,4,5)$, we get $(20,21,29)$. It would also be nice if this construction worked even if some sides were allowed to be interpreted as having negative lengths: say, $(-3,4,5)$ yields $(8,15,17)$, and $(-4,3,5)$ yields $(5,12,13)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

Comment: Your formula generates triples where $\,B-A=1.\quad$ Another formula that does so begins with a starting triple $\,(T)\,$ "seed" of
 $T_0=(0,0,1)$.
$$A_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+1\qquad  B_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+2 \qquad C_{n+1}=4A_n+3C_n+2$$
$$T_1=(3,4,5)\qquad T_2=(20,21,29)\qquad T_3=(119,120,168)\qquad T_4=(696,697,985)\qquad ...$$

Comment: Why not just draw this? Start with "c" in the middle or "a+b" as the sides of the square - kind of trivial.

Comment: @Moti So, are you saying that if we draw a square of side length $3a+3b+4c$ and partition each side into segments of length $2a+b+2c$ and $a+2b+2c$, going clockwise, then it would be trivial geometrically that the resulting inside square has length $2a+2b+3c$? Obviously, it's trivial algebraically, I was wondering if there is a nice drawing/tiling which makes it obvious geometrically.

Comment: @Alexander if you are right that the sides are of a right-angle triangle then it is a trivial drawing.

Comment: @Moti We know that the sides $a,b,c$ are of a right triangle, with $c$ as the hypotenuse. We don't know (a priori) that the same holds for $2a+b+2c,a+2b+2c,2a+2b+3c$. We want to show that using a drawing.

Comment: Are the three represent a Pythagorean triplet? Could you calculate it algebraically? Show it and I will draw for you!

Comment: Yes, it is a Pythagorean triplet, it's easy to check algebraically.